# Store private key in Android Keystore

Tags: java, android, encryption, keystore

I am developping an app that stores key in Android keystore, but I want this key to be **factory-reset-proof**. I have seen that keystore blobs are stored in `/data/misc/keystore/user_0/10043_USRSKEY_myUartKey` so I plan to manually backup this blob in a dedicated flash and to restore it after a factory reset.

This did work fine, I was able to recover encrypted data, even after factory reset, by restoring the keystore data from dedicated flash.

But during my tests I have observed that:

- restoring this `10043_USRSKEY_myUartKey` file to another device also allow this other device to decrypt ciphered data. My understanding was that it was no possible to extract key materials from a hardware backed keystore. May I have an issue in my TEE driver or in the keystore handling in my test app ?
- restoring this `10043_USRSKEY_myUartKey` file to the same device after changing PIN code did not cause any decryption issue. Again, my understanding was that pincode was part of the encryption so I don't understand how I can still decode 
  data ciphered with another PIN.
- I was also able to use this file to decrypt from another apk with different signature. So the key access is apparently not binded to the apk signature, should it ?

here is sample code that I use:

```
private void InitialiseKeystore() throws NoSuchProviderException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, PackageManager.NameNotFoundException, IOException, KeyStoreException, CertificateException {
    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
    keyStore.load(null);
    ArrayList<String> aliases = Collections.list(keyStore.aliases());
    for(String s : aliases){
        Log.d("ALIAS", s);
        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView)).append(String.format("Found key: %s\n", s));
        if(myAlias.equals(s)) return;
    }
    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView)).append("\nKey not found");
    //keyStore.deleteEntry("myUartKey");
    final KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator
            .getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES, "AndroidKeyStore");
    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView)).append("\nGENERATING KEY");
    final KeyGenParameterSpec keyGenParameterSpec = new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(myAlias,
            KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
            .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_GCM)
            .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_NONE)
            .build();

    keyGenerator.init(keyGenParameterSpec);
    final SecretKey secretKey = keyGenerator.generateKey();
    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView)).append("\nKEY GENERATED");
    final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
    byte iv[] = cipher.getIV();
    Log.w("IV", Arrays.toString(iv));
    final byte textToEncrypt[] = {0x00,0x11,0x22,0x33,0x44,0x55,0x66,0x77,(byte)0x88, (byte)0x99,(byte)0xaa,(byte)0xbb,(byte)0xcc,(byte)0xdd,(byte)0xee,(byte)0xff};
    byte encryption[] = cipher.doFinal(textToEncrypt);
    //Get data directory
    PackageManager m = getPackageManager();
    String s = getPackageName();
    PackageInfo p = m.getPackageInfo(s, 0);
    s = p.applicationInfo.dataDir;
    File file = new File(s + File.separator + "myEncryptedUartKey.bin");
    file.createNewFile();
    //write the bytes in file
    if(file.exists())
    {
        OutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(file);
        fo.write(iv);
        fo.write(encryption);
        fo.close();
        System.out.println("file created: "+file);
    }

    Log.i("ENC", Arrays.toString(encryption));
}
```

Comment: If you are able to copy the key to other device, it means that your physical device has no hardware support for AndroidKeystore. You are copying the keystore file. It is not an issue. But it is not supposed to be so easy to use in other device

Comment: About your third question, How  have you tested that the encryption key is available from other APK? The key should not be available through Android Keystore interface

Comment: I am root with SELinux disabled. I have replace keystore/user_0/app1_key content with keystore/user_0/app0_key. I thought that apk signature was part of encryption.